# Index of an element in haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I have these 2 lists `[@,a,@,b,c,@,@,@,(de),@,@,@,f,g,@,h]` and `["","","+","","","?","|","","","","","*","","","|",""]` and i want by using `scanl or map` function to cover the second list and also to extract the element in front of it in the first list. The 2 lists have different type of elements.

For example I want if the element in the second list is `/= ""` then to extract the element behind it in the first list (e.g. for for `+` to obtain `a`, for `? -> c` , `*->(de)` `|->g`).

I tried something like this

```
map(\x-> if x /= "" then l2 !! (((elemIndices x l1)!!0)-1) else Epsilon)l1
```

where `l1 is ["","","+","","","?","|","","","","","*","","","|",""]` and `l2 is [@,a,@,b,c,@,@,@,(de),@,@,@,f,g,@,h]` but it does't work, and also `@ = Epsilon` and it is from `data Reg = Epsilon | Literal Char | Or Reg Reg |  Then Reg Reg |  Star Reg  deriving Eq`.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: add one (unused) value to the start of first list and then use zipWith

Comment: What do you want to happen when the element from the second list is `""`? What do you want to happen when the first element of the second list is not `""`? What should the result be when the two lists you give are the input? (I assume it's a list, but show us the list.)

Comment: P.S. Your first list is not a valid Haskell list. It's easier for us to help you if you don't make up extensions to Haskell.

Comment: first list is String representation of [Reg]?

Comment: No, the 2 list represend the parsing of this expression : `a+bc?|(de)*fg|h`, the first is the first list without the letters and the second contains the letters tranformed in Reg variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like

```
combinedList = zip secondList (Epsilon : firstList)
```

And then to look up "?" you'd just do `lookup "?" combinedList` and get `Just (Literal 'c')`.

(You can obviously try grabbing the index, but it seems a bit roundabout for the case described here.)